# QRubberBand Selection - Stopping dotted line around selected items

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I am selecting items using the default QRubberBand enabled by setting `QGraphicsView.setDragMode()` to rubber band selection. This works fine, however when an item is selected it appears with a grey dotted line around it's bounding rect and I was wondering if there is any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the only way to do this is to override QGraphicsItem::paint().

The default implementation of paint() for standard items will change the pen if the item is selected or not. But since standard items likely consist of 1 line paint() calls changing this is trivial.

For example in a QGraphicsLineItem it would just be painter.drawLine( line() );